# Cancelling query during truncate

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I wanted to know what happens if i cancel query execution during truncate, are the records deleted? And is there any way to restore them?
Truncate was activated on table which contained 1,5 million records
From a little search in google i understand that the answer is no, but i wanted to be sure.
I'm using SQL Server 2005

Comment: If the truncate is part of a transaction that isn't committed, cancelling the query execution may result in the records being restored.

Comment: If you actually manage to cancel it mid truncate and aren't in an explicit transaction it will be rolled back as part of an auto commit transaction. Probably unlikely though as truncate is pretty quick and deferred truncate can be used for huge tables.

Comment: It wasn't a part of transaction. When i counted after cancellation it had only 300,000 records. I guess the rest is gone for good...

Comment: And if i've put all the records to temp table prior to truncating, it doesn't help me also, right?

Comment: @Alina - Unlikely to help you. If the data is important enough it might still be recoverable as it still exists on the data pages and you might be able to determine the deallocated pages from the transaction log (if that info is still in there) but I'm not aware of any utility that does this.

Answer (score 3):

`Truncate` deallocates the pages assigned to a table.

This is still atomic, in that you can cancel and have it rollback.  You can also enclose a `TRUNCATE` in an explicit transaction and perform a rollback.

Once you commit the transaction, though, the records are gone.  Unlike a `DELETE`, since the action is minimally logged, there is no record in the transaction log of the record contents.

Comment: Thanks, i'll be more careful next time...  very unfortunate

Answer (score 0):

Good explanation on [this](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/03/04/sql-server-rollback-truncate-command-in-transaction/) link

As I understand, if you have a transaction control, both DELETE and TRUNCATE can be rolled back.

The difference is, without a transaction, if you do a DELETE you can still recover your data with a restore of the log for example, what you cant do on a TRUNCATE, because the delete will will be logged row-by-row and the truncate, as @JNK pointed out, is minimally logged.